# onClick event in map function of ReactJS not firing

Tags: javascript, onclick, reactjs

I think I am missing something very simple here. My onClick event in map function isnt firing. I put a test hello function to test it out and it still doesnt seem to work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
window.PredictionContainer = React.createClass({
   mixins:[PredictionWatchMixin(predictionItems)],
   **hello: function(){
     alert("aasd");
     },**
     render:function(){
        var self = this;
        var matches = this.state.matches.map(function(match,i)
        {
          return (
          <div key={i} **onClick={self.hello}** className="post box padd">Some dummy text here </div>
          )
        });
        return (
          <div><PredictionTabs  tournament_id={this.props.tournament_id} onClick={this.updateEvent}/> {matches}  </div>
           );  
     }
);
```

Comment: where is onclick event defined?

Comment: Aside from the syntax error with the `**`s, there's no reason this wouldn't work unless some third party JavaScript is interfering.  The question can't be answered as-is.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and solved it like this:

```
var matches = this.state.matches.map(function(match,i)
        {
          return (
          <div key={i} **onClick={self.hello}** className="post box padd">Some dummy text here </div>
          )
        }.bind(this));
```